# Python virtualenv showing environment's name but working with main Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16 with python 2.7 and virtualenv.

I am running the env using `source bin/activate`, and the environment's name is showing in the terminal, which should say that it's active now.

But, when using `pip freeze`, I get the same packages that I installed in the main python on the machine. In addition I can't install using `pip install` without the `--user` flag, due to access denied error, which means that I am in fact not inside the new env.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please show us `echo $PATH`, `echo $PYTHONPATH` (just in case), `which python`and `which pip` after activating the virtual environment.